# Can machine learning can recognize "uncorrelation" between data and label?

Tags: machine-learning

Sorry for unclear title, but I was not sure how to put this into one sentence.

Recently, I found that there's a site (https://crimetest.ga/) which you can upload one's face picture then the model they trained will classify which type of crime you might possibly commit. They claim that they have trained the classifier model with real criminal faces dataset, however in common sense, there can be no correlation between someone's face and the crime he commits, and it has not been proven scientifically. (I think this site is made by someone who believe ML as a some kind of black box which can, if you put **any** data X with label Y and train a lot, it can classify any data into label Y.)

Anyway my question is... let's say there are data X and label Y with no such correlation or causal relation between them but we put them together in ML model anyway. Is there any study or paper about if the ML model can certainly recognize the "uncorrelation" between data X and label Y without making wrong assumption or bias? (So for the example above, can one model indicate that there's no correlation between face image and its crime label when the dataset is fed?)

Once again, sorry if my question is unclear or not enough. I had many troubles of describing the question I have in mind into clear English sentences.

p.s.
I have found that training neural network with random label can boost the training (https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.10455) but I don't know if this has something with my question.

**Edit**:
Just adding few words. If ML cannot recognize "uncorrelation" between data and label, does that mean if I want to know how much the data X and label Y are correleated (or if I desire the data X and label Y to be independent and want to check), it is never a good choice to use ML model for such task?

Comment: no? If I throw a coin, can you predict if I will win the lottery? no, because there is any type of correlation (they are independent events)... what they use are datasets filled with human biases, for example in  the USA is more likely that a black person will be incriminated for robbery than a white person, but it's not due to some special face characteristic, but by racial prejudice

Comment: in other words, is fair to say that the model is actually trained to predict a human bias than a possible crime... if not that it's just a random classifier that has a sort of seed based on some property of the image

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia So does that mean there is no way for ML model to recognize independence between train data X and label Y? Because if X and Y have some kind of latent correlation the model will **must** learn to that direction, and even if X and Y are perfectly independent the model will just won't know it forever?

Comment: if there is no correlation, the model will predict just the average (depends on the loss you use)... for example, I toss coin, you have to predict my income... thus your model will predict just the average for class head and average for class cross, that's the sign of independece (might also happen that the model capture spurious correlation or memorize the dataset, which is saw with a high accuracy in training very poor accuracy in test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no such correlation, you can just show that the predictions are not significantly better than the chance level. Using an equivalence test or non-inferiority test, you can show that the correlation is very likely close to 0 or lower than some small value. a

Now, the problem with those phrenology-like studies is not that they cannot correlate with the outcome, but that they would just learn to recognize class, race, socio-economic status, how grumpy or ugly your face is, and then present it as "objective" an innate propensity of the person to commit some crime. However, it is very far from being so.

E.g., you need to work an office job to commit securities fraud, and you are more likely to look a certain way if you work in an office, but that doesn't mean it would be good to now label every pale guy as a potential fraudster and hire truckers and roofers instead.

Comment: Thanks! I will try looking about equivalence test and non-inferiority test. Just one more, is it impossible for ML model **itself** to recognize the independence, rather than humans comparing the prediction and chance level?

Comment: you can have something like a sparse model that puts weights of some variables to 0, but I wouldn't call it that it recognizes that there is no correlation, and also people can always argue that you just have a bad model and a different model would find a relationship.

Answer (score 1):

There's a **yes** and a **no** to this.

For the **yes**, that is called overfitting, and it is the enemy of machine learning practitioners.

For the **no**, if the distribution of features is exactly the same for all levels of the outcome, then nothing will give you an ability to separate the distributions, not even a little bit. You might be able to overfit, just because the samples from those distributions are not identical, but that's all you have done; nothing can separate $N(0,1)$ from $N(0,1)$, for instance.

Back to the **yes**, however, machine learning might be able to find patterns that are real and useful, perhaps even highly predictive, even if they are unexpected.